# Rotating at a point in OpenGL

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, math

I have a cube that I want to move about in the XZ axis position. Every time the cube moves to another point in the grid it will rotate the cube. The cube will do a flip in 90degree. Here is the problem. The cube sinks a little into the gridbase whenever it's rotating. I have no idea how to fix this. Any suggestions?

```
if( (mvPosition.z - mvLastPosition.z) > 0 || (mvPosition.z - mvLastPosition.z) < 0)
{
    glRotatef( (mvPosition.z - mvLastPosition.z) * 90.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}
else if ( (mvPosition.x - mvLastPosition.x) > 0 || (mvPosition.x - mvLastPosition.x) < 0  )
{
    glRotatef( (mvPosition.x - mvLastPosition.x) * -90.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Comment: all i can think about: with your code you accumulating calculation errors, which are inevitable with floating-point arithmetics. A way to fix this is NOT just to update old matrices with glRotatef, but reset them with glLoadIdentity() and calculate new ones every frame.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for the advice. Fairly new to OpenGL, so could use all the help I can get! Not to be an ass, but is there a way to flip the cube on a fixed point. From what I've been researching on, I have to translate the origin to the point of rotation and translate again. But I pretty much lost it at translating the origin...